# Non-commercial Tabletop RPGs using the Games Workship IP guidelines?

Tags: intellectual-property, games

It was suggested I post here instead of RPG stackoverflow :)

I’m trying to figure out to what extent fan Tabletop RPGs set in the 40k universe are allowed, clearly anything commercial is off the table — but as soon as it is explicitly non-commercial, it does seem in line with the guidelines?

https://www.games-workshop.com/en-US/Intellectual-Property-Guidelines

**Quotes of interest**

> Fan-fiction, hobby books and magazines
> Individuals may write their own stories, hobby books and magazines based on our characters and settings, but these must: not include text, artwork or imagery copied from any official Games Workshop material
> be non-commercial, with no money being received or paid…….

- Do RPGs classify as hobby books?

> Games and apps – individuals must not create computer games or apps based on our characters and settings. These are only to be created under licence from Games Workshop.

- This only seems to apply to a digital medium.

**My questions:**

- Do you interpret non-commercial TTRPGs as being in-line with the guidelines? Is my read too favorable?
- Hobby books must not include GW produced text, does this include individual names as well? (is using space marines or astartes off-limits etc?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a crosspost from https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204173/30306

Comment: @Trish I actually suggested it get posted over here,  as it's actually a legal question that just happens to take place in the milieu of rpgs.